# I cannot install vim manually on my MAC with python 3.10 or more plugins

Tags: python, vim, makefile

I have a problem I don't know how to solve. I'm currently trying to install vim manually, without any package manager like `Homebrew` or `Macports`, because I don't have and I cannot have the administrators password and I don't want to use the package managers I mentioned before in order to practice installing programs on my own.

I already have successfully installed `python3.10.10` with the source code, and added the binaries to the `PATH` environmental variable, which is:

```
/Users/myuser/local_bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

as you can see here:

```
➜  ~ python3
Python 3.10.10 (main, Mar  9 2023, 17:35:07) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have `vim 9.0.13` downloaded, and what I did was to do the command to configure it:

```
./configure --enable-python3interp \
--with-python3-command=$HOME/local/python3.10.10/bin/python3
```

where `$HOME/local/python3.10.10/bin/python3` is where I installed python and where specifically my binary is.

Also, in the vim `Makefile` I modified the prefix and exec_profile variables, so that it will be installed in my personal local folders:

```
prefix = $(HOME)/local/vim90
exec_prefix = $(HOME)/local_bin
```

Then what I did is the normal commands to compile and install vim:

```
make
make install
```

After all this, it installes vim correctly, but when I do into the vim console `:version`, python3 is not included as a feature:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Mar 10 2023 12:19:21)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-1393
Compiled by ----------
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
-balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term -gettext           +num64             +textobjects
-browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     -perl              +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have [`+python/dyn`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+%22python%2Fdyn%22) which means that `libpython` is downloaded on demand. Though I think it's Python2-only.

Comment: https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+python/dyn

Comment: @phd, my problem is that I cannot install python3, not that I cannot find the python commands

Comment: Step #1, install [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/tag/release-176) like any other Mac application. Step #2, read `:help mvim`. Step #3, add `alias vim='mvim -v'` to your shell's configuration script. Problem solved.

Comment: @romainl Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to know how to do it as I'm doing it, but if there are not other suggestions, I would follow your advice

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Some how the ./configure.sh was not working as expected. But the workaround is you can manually edit the Makefile and enable the python flags.

1. Open src/Makefile
2. Uncomment the python flags and build by running "make".

   CONF_OPT_PYTHON3 = --enable-python3interp
   CONF_OPT_PYTHON3 = --enable-python3interp --with-python3-command=python3.6
   CONF_OPT_PYTHON3 = --enable-python3interp=dynamic